# how to play dailymotion video in android

Tags: android, webview, android-videoview, android-2.2-froyo

I am a beginner to android . I create the app in android 2.2 . I want to play thirdparty video on my app. I played the youtube video using the webview. I try to play a dailymotion video in webview it shows the video thumbnail and the play icon . when I click the play icon the video is not play?  please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Get your video's embed code in Dailymotion and assign it videoHtml like this;

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    videoHtml = "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xznb64\"></iframe><br /><a href=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xznb64_leyla-ile-mecnun-dan-evlilik-programlarina-gonderme_news\" target=\"_blank\">Leyla İle Mecnun&#039;dan Evlilik Programlarına...</a> <i>ile  <a href=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/trthaber\" target=\"_blank\">trthaber</a></i>";
    webView.loadData(videoHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
        contetView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    } else {
        contetView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    }
```